# Cordova globalThis is not defined error after updation cordova to 10.0.0

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, cordova-plugins, node-modules

Hi I have developed a cordova app using cordova version 8.1.0 but when i went to upload it , play store gave error that my app targets API LEVEL 28 and i need to upload app which target API level 29 atleast, I then update cordova to 10.0.0 after that I cant build app neither can do anything its throwing globalThis not defined even if i try to check cordova -version. npm version i have is 3.10.10

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\karan>cordova -version
C:\Users\karan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\queue-micro
task\index.js:5
  ? queueMicrotask.bind(globalThis)
                        ^

ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\karan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordo
va\node_modules\queue-microtask\index.js:5:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\karan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordo
va\node_modules\run-parallel\index.js:4:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so for this problem the solution is to update the npm version too.

But now I am having trouble installing cordova-plugin-firebase-lib , Sometimes it throws errr color.xml already exists and sometime say dont have permission

Answer (score 0):

I had just experienced the same issue on MacOS, share some thoughts for your reference.

If you had switched the node(&npm) version by something like nvm on the MacOS (not sure there's any equivalent on Windows). After switching you have to reinstall the cordova, as the node version changed, your cordova version may vary, so you have to keep it up to the node(npm) version.

```
npm -g install cordova
```

And then, execute:

```
cordova prepare
```

again.